# Conjugation with ни/либо phrases

Tags: грамматика

Which conjugation of the verb is used in a sentence like, "Neither I nor he will go to the party," where the subjects are different?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We use plural verb forms in such sentences for all tenses.

> Ни он, ни я ничего не сделаем. Ни он, ни я ничего не сделали.
>
> Либо он,либо я купим подарок. Либо он,либо она не закрыли дверь.

But whenever the verb comes after one of the subjects, the verb agrees with it.

> Ни он ничего не сделал, ни она.
>
> Ни я ничего не сделала, ни он.